# Will this work on phone gap?

Tags: android, cordova, camera

I want to have an aspect of an app that calls up the camera based on a preset time and then gives the user some like five seconds and then automatically takes a picture without the user giving any input except to direct the position.  Do you know if I can pull this off with phone gap? I've looked at the API and I cannot see it exactly but I feel like it should be possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the answer to your question. But if you can do it in Java, then you can do it with PhoneGap.

The only problem is that if PhoneGap doesn't provide the API for what you want, you'll have to write a plugin for it and therefore know how to write Java

[How to create a PhoneGap plugin for Android](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/36753494/How%20to%20Create%20a%20PhoneGap%20Plugin%20for%20Android)

Answer (score 0):

No, PhoneGap can't do that. And instead of writing a plugin I would choose writing a whole native application

Answer (score 0):

Hello please use java script timer to schedule the camera and use phone gap camera api to take shot as per your set time duration.